# Is it too soon to use Rails 4.0?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm a beginner to Ruby on Rails and have been learning based on books teaching Rails 3.0.

My question is:

Should I be learning the newer syntax coming and get ready to use Rails 4.0 instead? Or will that limit my options in terms of plugins and stuff I would be able to use?

I don't want to spend time mastering soon-to-be deprecated syntax, but I also don't want start learning/using Rails 4.0 if the changes are so drastic that resources and plugins available based on 3.0 are going to be unusable.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: This is probably better posted on Programmers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should know the changes that will happen in Rails 4, but it will always be beneficial to understand Rails 3 code as well. Many of the examples online are in Rails 3 (or even Rails 2). You should know how to recognize something has been deprecated and how you can do the same thing in Rails 4.

Answer (score 0):

As Logan mention earlier it will beneficial if you know the Rails 3 code as most apps and tutorials will be written on that version.

Also, I don't think that the changes between Rails 3 and at the initial Rails 4 is that different that will make Rails 3 code be depreciated. Have a look at [RailsCast's video](http://railscasts.com/episodes/400-what-s-new-in-rails-4) on what is changing in a nutshell.

Another recommendation is to install both versions on your machines using RVM so that you can learn and navigate through both worlds.